# Formas Normais modelagem de dados

Tags: modelagem, normalização

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Tenho um arquivo `excell` com informações do PRODUTO E PEDIDO. Ele esta fora das formas normais, pois as informações estão todas em uma tabela só.

Estou subindo através de `bulk insert` essas informações para um banco no SQLServer. A primeira tabela da imagem mostra como ela é atualmente. As outras duas como devem ficar apos a normalização. Como proceder para associar o novo campo criado na tabela produtos(CodigoProduto)com o pedido? Já que na primeira tabela desnormalizada não existem informações para esse campo?

Comment: Você esta criando a tabela Produtos ou irá utilizar uma existente para efetuar o relacionamento?

Comment: Estou criando a tabela Produto mas com base nas informações que eu ja tenho. Entao nessas informações eu nao tenho um codigo de produto.

Comment: Faça o `bulk insert` na tabela Produtos somente com a descrição e depois acrescente a `primary key`.

Comment: Ok, isso é facil. O problema é: na tabela do excel eu tenho uma linha só. Ex:

Comment: Você quer incluir os novos produtos em uma tabela já existente e com a `primary key` definida?

Comment: Isso é facil fazer, acontece que a partir do momento que eu separar as informações de produto como cor, nome, tamanho. Ela vai ficar perdida e eu nao vou saber mais a qual produto ela pertence. Na tabela excel que tenho esta assim: NomeFulano, CodigoFulano, EndereçoFulano, DataPedido, NumeroPedido, NomeProduto, CorProduto, tamanhoProduto. Note que Tenho o campo CodigoFulano, posso usar como pk na table Cliente, e tambem tenho NumeroPedido, mas nao tenho CodigoProduto.

Comment: Pode resolver isso manualmente cadastrando 1 a 1 os relacionamentos caso não tenha muitos dados. Por exemplo ,se tiver somente uns 100 registros, faça na mão mesmo pois o custo de tempo será igual ou menor do que criar um script para automatizar a migração dos dados. Se for mais de 400, 1000, etc, talvez seja mais viável criar uma automação. No caso de uma automação, uma lógica mais simples é setar o campo do código do produto de acordo com o nome do mesmo. Mas deve observar também o campo "corProduto".

Answer (score 1):

Sugestão de como proceder:

1. Faça o `bulk insert` de todo o arquivo excel, inclusive com a
   Descrição do Produto para um tabela do bd.
2. Crie a tabela de Produtos com as descrições do produto e depois
   adicione a `primary key`.
3. Crie o campo Código do Produto na tabela com a descrição do produto
   e os outros campos.
4. Atualize o campo Código do produto usando a Descrição do Produto das
   duas tabelas para fazer a associação (`join`).
5. Exclua o campo descrição do produto da tabela e só deixe na tabela
   produto.

Sei que não é uma boa prática fazer `join` com campos string, mas, como é só com paliativo, acho que não terá problemas.

Comment: @Felipe Gomes Coloque as imagens no post.

Comment: Coloquei as imagens no post agora. Desculpe ainda sou noob no forum.